# Race till first resolve, or all reject (inverse of all)

Tags: redux-saga

I am trying to create a saga that runs multiple `fetch` in a parallel, and it should go until the first `fetch` resolves, OR all `fetch` reject. I could not figure this feature out.

I was experimenting with `race` but this is completing a race with even the first reject. Here is my saga:

```
const pingOfflineSaga = function* pingOfflineSaga() {
    while (true) {
        yield take(PING_OFFLINE);

        const OFFLINE_SERVERS = ['https://duckduckgo.com/', 'https://www.bing.com/', 'https://www.google.com/'];


        const responses = yield race(OFFLINE_SERVERS.reduce((acc, server) => {
            acc[server] = call(fetch200, server);
            return acc;
        }, {}));

        const [ res ] = Object.values(responses);
        if (res === true) {
            yield put(update({ isOffline:undefined }));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to resolve as soon as I get the first 200 status response. `fetch200` is this:

```
async function fetch200(url) {
    let res;
    try {
        res = await fetch(url);
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(`fetch200 :: Fetch errored with message: ${err.message}`);
    }
    if (res.status === 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Error('fetch200 :: Fetch did not get 200 status');
    }
}
```

The inverse of `all` effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use bluebird's [`Promise.any`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.any.html) method

```
const pingOfflineSaga = function* pingOfflineSaga() {
    while (true) {
        yield take(PING_OFFLINE);   
        const OFFLINE_SERVERS = ['https://duckduckgo.com/', 'https://www.bing.com/', 'https://www.google.com/'];    
        const promises = OFFLINE_SERVERS.map(server => fetch(server));            
        result = yield call(Promise.any, promises);

        if (result) {
            yield put(update({ isOffline:undefined }));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fuzzy, I was looking for a way to to do it with using just redux-saga effects. Worst case I can do a `throw` if I find status 200 in `fetch200` and use the `all` effect. But now `throw` is not bad, its what Im going for, "first throw". But I prefer to not because this isnt the easiest to reason about, its like inverse logic haha.